# Learning JavaScript by reading first or writing first?

Tags: javascript

I did check (and read) a few similar questions here, but this really applies to everyone differently since no one learns the same.

My question is not on what resources to use, for that I have plenty.

I am working my way through JavaScript: The Definitive Guide (and I have the good parts as well).

I'm reading up on the core language but I don't feel like the information is sticking (or rather I'm not getting much out of it).

My question is should I just write an application in JavaScript and reference my books (I'm a very hands on person, but do enjoy reading), or should I keep reading the book, do the exercises, and then write a program?

In short: should I just write js app first and reference my book, or read the book first doing the examples and then write a js application? I've done some basic programming in PHP/Python (nothing meaningful yet).

I always learn math this way and I suppose, I'm conflicted in how I should tackle learning a language. I feel like I could read many books, but perhaps this isn't the best way for me (I know others learn differently).

For starts, I'm considering writing a simple calculator in JS.

Comment: As you said in your question, everyone learns differently. You know what works best for you, so stick with that! Personally, I prefer to just try writing some code to learn, rather than reading though a bunch of books.

Answer (score 2):

Like for any languages I would suggest to do both.

You have to immediately start applying what you are studying. This way you will focus what you learned and understand better how the language works.

JavaScript is a highly flexible language. You can start soft, then learn new things each day and it will grow with you. You will never stop learning with JavaScript because it's easy to start but difficult to master.

You can start with really small scripts. When you start to feel confident you can create more advanced scripts, start using frameworks, write plugins for them, and ultimately your own library of functions.

I only suggest you to start learning [best practices](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts) as soon as possible, because there are many things you have to avoid while programming in JS.

Then as a last word, always do what you feel like is better, don't go crazy trying to learn everything immediately. Everyone learns and works at his own pace.

Comment: Thanks so much for the kind answers guys! With this, I am ready to tackle any language. :)